# DataTables no funcionan mis botones

Tags: javascript, datatables

¡Hola!,resulta que no me funcionan los botones para exportar a excel,pdf e imprimir, y solamente me muestra un icono de carga, quisiera poder resolver esto , adjunto información, si necesitan más contexto , estaré gustoso de mostrarlo :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#example').DataTable({        
        language: {
                "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
                "info": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                "infoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                "sSearch": "Buscar:",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sFirst": "Primero",
                    "sLast":"Último",
                    "sNext":"Siguiente",
                    "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                 },
                 "sProcessing":"Procesando...",
            },
        //para usar los botones   
        responsive: "true",
        dom: 'Bfrtilp',       
        buttons:[ 
            {
                extend:    'excelHtml5',
                text:      'Exportar Excel ',
                titleAttr: 'Exportar a Excel',
                className: 'btn btn-success',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10 , 11 , 12 , 13, 14]
                }
            },
            {
                extend:    'pdfHtml5',
                text:      'Exportar PDF ',
                titleAttr: 'Exportar a PDF',
                className: 'btn btn-danger',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 6 , 7  , 10 , 11 , 13 , 14 ]
                }
                
            },
            {
                extend:    'print',
                text:      'Imprimir',
                titleAttr: 'Imprimir',
                className: 'btn btn-info',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 6 , 7 , 11 , 13 , 14]
                }
            },
            
        ]
        
    });     
});
```

[image: Este es el error que me indica al presionar uno de los btns a continuacion]

[image: Me muestra un icono cargando y me sale el error mencionado]

(Editado)

```html
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <title>Prueba</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../assets/img/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
```

y estos son los scripts :

```html
    <script src="../../js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../js/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../../js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../js/main.js"></script>

    <!-- datatables con bootstrap -->
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Para usar los botones -->

    <!--DataTables Botones -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../datatables/JSZip-2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../datatables/pdfmake-0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../datatables/pdfmake-0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../datatables/Buttons-1.5.6/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../datatables/Buttons-1.5.6/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../datatables/Buttons-1.5.6/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../js/datatables.js"></script>
```

Comment: Deberias agregar como incluyes la libreria y tu HTML

Comment: @alanfcm Agregado!

Comment: @alanfcm Resulta que cuando hago este script en el DOM , abriendo una etiqueta me funcionan los btnes , pero cuando lo llamo como archivo no me funciona los btnes, pero me aparece el btn de filtrado , para poder mostrar 10 , 20 o 50 o 100 registros , quiero que se me muestre ese filtrado y a su vez que los btnes esten activos

Comment: Pero se desactiva los btnes cuando lo llamo de forma externa por ruta pero me aparece en btn de filtrado

Comment: Y en caso contrario , al cargarlo en el dom me funcionan los btnes pero no me aparece el btn de filtrado

Comment: Parece que el error pasa cuando el numero de columnas que tienes no concuerda con lo que declaraste en javascript usando `columns`

Answer (score 1):

Según foros de dataTables es una incongruencias entre la cantidad de columnas en el header y filas. Me ha pasado que no me doy cuenta y coloco en el header 6 columnas y en las filas solo 5 y me tira ese error.